# Material-UI & React - changing <input> to <TextField> stops form submit from working?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I have a form featuring an input and a button for adding tasks to my CRUD Todo app. I originally had this in plain HTML to get the functionality up and running and then introduced Material-UI to make things look a tad better.

However, my form for submitting new tasks to the list no longer works due to the `<TextField>` that replaces the `<input>`, and I cannot figure out why.

I get a few errors when running the TextField, mainly when it is trying to pass its props down the line. **BUT** when I change the TextField back to an input and keep everything else in its Material-UI variant, it actually works. This leads me to think that it is some functionality that I am missing with the TextField.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Working code (input with material buttons)**

```
render() {
        return(
            <form ref="inputForm" onSubmit={this.handleCreate.bind(this)}>
                <input type="text" ref="createInput" placholder="task..."/>
                <button>Create</button>
                {this.renderError()}
            </form>
        )
    }
```

**Broken code (TextField with material buttons)**

```
render() {
        return(
            <form ref="inputForm" onSubmit={this.handleCreate.bind(this)}>
                <TextField name="CreateNew" type="text" ref="createInput" placholder="task..."/>
                <FlatButton type="submit">Create</FlatButton>
                {this.renderError()}
            </form>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem was in both the definition of the element and the function it was calling also.

I needed to have `<FlatButton type="submit">...` as I had thought of previously, but I was also trying to get the value of the form itself, rather than the Textfield ref.

I also found that the text entered within the TextField needed to be accessed via `this.refs.createInput.input.value`.

Please see below for the function to go along with the HTML

```
render() {
    return(
        <form name="newForm" ref="inputForm" onSubmit={this.handleCreate.bind(this)}>
            <TextField name="CreateNew" type="text" ref="createInput" placholder="task..."/>
            <FlatButton type="submit">Create</FlatButton>
            {this.renderError()}
        </form>
    )
}

handleCreate(event) {
    console.log("clicked")
    event.preventDefault();

    const createInput = this.refs.createInput.input;
    const task = createInput.value;
    // Capitalise first letter of input (ie. newTask ==> NewTask)
    const Task = this.capitalise(task);
    // Validate task has been input and is not a clone
    const validateInput = this.validateInput(Task);

    if (validateInput) {
        console.log("if(validateInput")
        this.setState({ error: validateInput})
        return;
    }

    this.setState({ error: null });
    if(createInput) {
        this.props.createTask(Task);
        this.refs.inputForm.reset();
    }
}
```